# Length *vs* table of characters

Tags: finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group. Its *length* $\ell(G)$ is the length $n$ of any Jordan-Hölder filtration $1=G_n\subset\cdots\subset G_0=G$ ($G_i$ is normal in $G_{i-1}$ and $G_{i-1}/G_i$ is simple).

> Can $\ell(G)$ be read (easily) in the table of characters of $G$ ?

For instance $\ell(G)=1$ (that is $G\ne1$ is simple) if and only if there does not exist a character $\chi\ne\bf1$ such that $\chi(g)=\chi(e)$ for some $g\ne e$.

A **suggestion** for starting: consider the case of a $p$-group of order $p^m$. Because its J-H factors are $p$-groups and simple, they are all isomorphic to $C_p$ and therefore $\ell(G)=m$. Is there any general fact concerning the table of $p$-groups, that is directly related to $m$ ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the character table does allow one to locate the normal subgroups (as unions of some conjugacy classes).    From this you can probably recover the length, but I'd have to check the details.

Comment: @Jim. I agree with your first sentence (this is basically what I meant when I considered the case $\ell(G)=1$). However, once you know the list of normal subgroups, how do you reconstruct the Joradn-Hölder factors ?

Comment: Do you mean that $\ell(G) = 1$ if and only if there *does not* exist a character $\chi\neq 1$ such that...?

Comment: @benblumsmith. Yes of course ! I fix it immediately.

Comment: On second thought, I doubt that the character table determines the length (though I don't have good counterexamples at hand).    While it's easy to identify normal subgroups, it's much harder to pass from the character table of $G$ to that of a proper subgroup (as seen in going from $S_n$ to $A_n$).

Comment: Note that the length of any solvable group is the number of prime factors in its order (counted with multiplicity). Moreover, the order of a group is recoverable from its character table, as $\sum \chi(1)^2$. Thus, to have a hope of building a counter-example, we need to use non-solvable groups.

Comment: @David. Of course I know the relation $|G|=\sum\chi(e)^2$, but because it gives only the order of the group, which does not determine the length, one needs something else in the table.

Comment: David's point is that to answer your question in the negative you need two groups with the same character table but different lengths; this and the observation about the order shows that one of these groups must be non-solvable.

Comment: Answer to a related question: the length is uniquely determined by the character table, as a consequence of the classification of finite simple groups. This is because if $G$ is the direct product of isomorphic finite simple groups, the number of factors in the direct product is determined by $|G|$. This appears in W. Kimmerle et al., Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 60 (1990), no. 1, 89–122, and uses CFSG.